# Valid answer, but voted to delete

Tags: discussion

I have [answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/340314/164670) to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340135/find-nearest-best-fit-for-circle/340314#340314) question. However it's voted to delete by 2 users.

[image]

There is no explanation why it's a sub standard answer. How do I suppose to update the answer to acceptable level?

Comment: do you ask about [first version](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/340314/1) or current one? There seem to be quite a bunch of [edits](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/340314/revisions) made to this answer, especially in Rev 3

Comment: I'm referring to the current one. As I remember the negative votes were not in there until I finished all 3 versions. I don't have a way to know when these close votes are made, but I guess they probably done at the same time when the negative votes made.

Comment: See my comment below your answer.

Comment: Please note that delete votes can only be cast on an answer with a negative score (moderators can delete anything, however). Now that your answer has a non-negative score, the delete link (for 20k users) does not show up anymore. Meaning the odds are that your answer will not be deleted.